# How to properly display iPhone Address Book in Landscape mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've added an ABPeoplePickerNavigationController but it doesn't display correctly in landscape.  I'm using the iPhone SDK 2.2.

```
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *ab = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
[ab setPeoplePickerDelegate:self];
[self presentModalViewController:ab animated:YES];
```

It displays like this with the search bar being cut off:
screencast.com/t/4gVhonWFzT8

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deployed the address book as-is on the device. It just shows up weird on the simulator.  It shows up fine in landscape on the device.

Answer (score 0):

currently there is no landscape view for the Address Book if you are using the 2.2.1 SDK.